# Make a link background as wide as the container

Tags: html, css

How can I make a link's background as wide as the container it's inside?
My current code:

```css
.menu {
 width: 500px;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: gray;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 position: fixed;
}

.menu_content {
 top: 50px;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
}

a.menuBtn, a.menuBtn:visited {
 background-color: blue;
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 padding-right: 500px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu_content">
   <a href="#" class="menuBtn">Start</a>
   
  </div>
 </div>
```

I want it to, no matter how long the link-text is, have the blue background as wide as the gray background. And the link-text to be 20px in from the left.

Currently the blue background gets wider if the text is longer, due to the padding. Tried a padding-right: 100% but obviously that didn't work. *Worth a shot though*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a.menuBtn{ 
    display: block;
}`

And remove the `padding-right:500px`

Comment: ah, thanks! Removed all paddings except the padding-left and it works great now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS's `calc()` function and `display` property on `.menuBtn` and remove the extra padding.

Like:

```
.menuBtn {
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% - 20px); /* Total Width (100%) - Padding (20px) */
}
```

```css
.menu {
 width: 500px;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: gray;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 position: fixed;
}

.menu_content {
 top: 50px;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
}

a.menuBtn, a.menuBtn:visited {
 background-color: blue;
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 /* padding-right: 500px; */
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
}

.menuBtn {
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu_content">
   <a href="#" class="menuBtn">Start</a>
   
  </div>
 </div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `width` property from `.menu` class:

```
.menu {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Now, no matter how long the link is, `.menu` div will have the same width.

**Edit:**
Or if you want the div to be **at least** 500px in width give him `min-width: 500px;` property instead of `width`

Comment: I think you missunderstood this, the .menu is the correct size. I never want that width to change. It's the blue background (from the link) that I want fixed at the same width

Answer (score 0):

```
use below css.

.menu {
            width: 500px;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: gray;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            position: fixed;
        }

        .menu_content {
            top: 50px;
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 20px 0;
            background-color: blue;
        }

        a.menuBtn, a.menuBtn:visited {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;
            padding: 0 15px;
            width: 100%;
        }
```

Comment: Not the result I wanted, that just made a blue block in the whole menu_content. I only want the blue background from the link, not the whole content div

Answer (score 0):

I've added one more div as wrapper of the link with CSS:

```
.menuBtnWrapper {  
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```css
.menu {
 width: 500px;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: gray;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 position: fixed;
}

.menu_content {
 top: 50px;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}

a.menuBtn, a.menuBtn:visited {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
}

.menuBtnWrapper {  
 padding: 20px;
 background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu_content">
          <div class="menuBtnWrapper">  
   <a href="#" class="menuBtn">Start</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Will try this out!

Comment: Didn't get the result I was expecting, since I'm also using a hover on the link to change the bg, it didn't work as I'd like it to. Thanks anyways, found another solution! :)